# Chain Rule applied to Trig Functions

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Given $f(x)= \sin(\pi x)^{2}$, find the derivative.

Using the chain rule my work is as follows:  $(\sin(\pi x)^2)'$ becomes
$$2 \sin(\pi x) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(\sin(\pi x)$$
The derivative of sin is cos, thus
$$2 \sin(\pi x) \cdot \cos(\pi x) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(\pi x)$$ 
The derivative of $\pi x$ is $\pi$, and the equation stretches to

$$2 \sin(\pi x) \cos(\pi x) \pi == 2 \pi \sin(\pi x) \cos(\pi x)$$

However, the book states the answer as $$2 \pi^{2}~ x ~\cos(\pi x)^{2}$$ and that definitely doesn't match my result.  Where did I go wrong?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Arturo Madigan, Jonas Meyer, et al for their help.

I re-did the problem based on having $(\pi x)^{2}$, having the exponent rather than the sin function, and it seems I have a missing exponent as well.

Differentiating the terms of the function via the chain rule, I get $$(\pi x)^{2} [\frac{d}{dx}sin] \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(\pi x)^{2}$$

$$ cos(\pi x)^{2} \cdot 2\pi x= 2~\pi~ x cos~(\pi x)^{2}$$

According to the book answer, $2~\pi x$ should actually be $2~ \pi^{2} x$

Comment: I don't think you have given the correct function.  Was the original function $f(x)=\sin((\pi x)^2)$?  It may have been written as $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)^2$, which is ambiguous, but you seem to have misinterpreted it as $(\sin(\pi x))^2=\sin^2(\pi x)$, and you wrote $\sin(\pi x)$.  Will you please clarify?

Comment: How did you go from $f(x)= sin(\pi x)$ to (it appears) $f'(x)=2 sin(\pi x) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(sin(\pi x))$?  The $2\sin(\pi x)$ appeared out of nowhere and there are mismatched parentheses.  
But Jonas Meyer may have a better guess.

Comment: @Ross Millikan, $2 sin(\pi x)$ is the derivative of $sin(\pi x)$ in the first stop using the chain rule.  My work posted shows my attempt at going into the function.  @Jonas Meyer, I wrote the function as it appears in the book.  There is only one set of parenthesis, and the exponent is outside it.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer, its been edited.  My mistake.

Comment: @Jason: Thank you.  The missing exponent was the reason for PEV's and Dactyl's answers.

Comment: @Jonas:  I, too, do not see an exponent.  But I also object to "becomes" as I think of that as a synonym of "equals", where here it is used like "the derivative is".

Comment: @Jonas: I agree with Ross; once the missing exponent is added, you should really have a derivative before saying that it "becomes" or "equals" $2\sin(\pi x)\frac{d}{dx}\sin(\pi x)$. (Given that you were doing the derivative of $\sin^2(\pi x)$)

Comment: @Ross, @Arturo: Have you both made the same anagrammatical error (swapping 'Jason' for 'Jonas')?

Comment: @Jonas:  I plead guilty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the answer, the question was for the derivative of $\sin\Bigl( (\pi x)^2\Bigr)$; instead, you computed the derivative of $\Bigl(\sin(\pi x)\Bigr)^2$.

If you were computing the derivative of the latter, then your computations are correct; the derivative is $2\pi\sin(\pi x)\cos(\pi x)$.

But if you were asked for the derivative of $\sin\Bigl((\pi x)^2\Bigr)$, then of course you were looking at the wrong function, and that's why the answers don't match.

It's possible you had "$\sin(\pi x)^2$" and interpreted this as $(\sin(\pi x))^2$; usually, $\sin^2(\pi x)$ is used for the latter, so "$\sin(\pi x)^2$" would be interpreted as $\sin\Bigl((\pi x)^2\Bigr)$.

Comment: but how do you know which to compute for?  The book does give examples of how parenthesis placement can affect computation but $sin x^{2}$ can also be written as $sin^{2} x$, which adds to my confusion

Comment: @Ross Millikan, I'd definitely say the math prof & book play a large part, but I also have to factor in my lack of sleep studying for the exam.  The prof is a great guy, but its very hard to follow along with what he's saying in the class, which is why I have my laptop running the whole time so I can double-check what he's talking about.

Comment: @Jason: Since I would use $\sin^2(\pi x)$ for the function $\Bigl(\sin (\pi x)\Bigr)^2$, then it seems reasonable that the *other* notation, $\sin (\pi x)^2$, is being used to mean *something else*, namely $\sin\Bigl( (\pi x)^2\Bigr)$. It's bad use of notation on the part of the book (there should be that second set of parentheses to make everything clear), but it's a process of elimination ("if they had meant `x` they would have written it `this way`; they didn't write it `this way`, so they must have meant `y` instead").

Comment: I'm reminded of a sign that was supposedly posted in a newsroom (back in the day of lead type)-"the composing room has an infinite supply of periods to terminate short, complete sentences".  Maybe that applies to parentheses, too.  We got lots of 'em, so use 'em liberally.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the function $\sin(\pi x)$ like this: $x \to \pi x \to \sin(\pi x)$. In which case it is intuitively clear that the rate of change of the function should be the multiplication of the rate of changes of $x \to \pi x$ and $y \to \sin (y)$, the latter being evaluated at $y=x$. Hence PEV's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative is $\pi \cos(\pi x)$.

Comment: You're right, but why does the sin cancel out in the book answer?

Comment: Based on the OP's steps and the answer in the back of the book, I'm pretty sure $\sin(\pi x)$ was not intended. (I elaborate in my comment on the question.)